# Identify old dos system file type and decode it into text file

Tags: bin

I have pick up an old dos system from my friend, and I need to import the data into SQL, but before importing the data, i need to decode it into a readable text file, but I failed to do so. I have try several stuff:

- file command in ubuntu terminal, it said "data"
- Use [online trid](http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.py) and it said macbin(MacBinary 1)
- Tried bin2hex, but couldn't unhex it
- Tried some online macbin to hex, no luck as well
- Tried to open in macOS, but it keep extracting files
- bin2hex said, nothing here
- stuffitexpander.... Doesn't recognize...

This is the file that i need to decode
https://gofile.io/?c=wdbs6A

Please let me know if you need the original program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are just some database files.

Use [**this site**](https://filext.com/file-extension/DB) for explanations. they even have a file analyzer - showing you the data inside.

You will need to rename the files to `.db` extension instead of `.ocm`.

Comment: Yeah, finally, i was weird when it was a macbin file when i analyzed it online. Now it display the data in nice format from the site you have given me, but i don't know what program i can use to extract the data and convert it into mysql, any recommendations?

Comment: The site is able to analyze my data but when I use LiteDB as suggested by the site, I failed to open the file. The link is the [image of the analyzer](https://ibb.co/3pLnWSB) and [error by LiteDB](https://ibb.co/z7Dsyn9), thank you very much!

Comment: I think that the smaller file is either empty or corrupted / damaged somehow.

Comment: That's weird, the system reading it without problem and the site doesn't have problem analyze the data

Comment: It is also possible that the version of LIteDB does not match, or it is actually some other flavor of database, not fully compatible with LiteDB. You need to remember that the original files were `.ocm`. Maybe you can find in the old DOS system which programs are installed, and then which one of them can open the files.

Comment: My guess is the OCM extension is fake, because the system named OCM. Should I provide the whole program? I'm not really into DOS system.

Comment: No need to provide anything. Just scavenge the system for the installed software, understand which software deals with databases, see which db software creates those kinds of files.

Comment: It runs a BTRIEVE.EXE before running the main program. I guess this is it?